# (jenkins plugin-generic webhook trigger) integrated with Beanstalk how to Specify triggered Branch

Tags: jenkins, webhooks

I have a beanstalk, want to trigger my jenkins Job after pushing/merge to Dev branch. Do you guys know how to set specific branch using generic-webhook-trigger ?
in my beanstalk i already set classic webhook pointed to http://user:pass@jenkinsIP/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke.

actually i already try jenkins job configuration like this :

[image: jenkins job configuration]

Comment: Did you have a look at the wiki page? https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin

There is also an example with Gitlab here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Violation+Comments+to+GitLab+Plugin

The webhook content being posted from Beanstalk is needed to answer this question.